# Выскакивает ошибка: Входная строка имела неверный формат

Tags: c#, .net

```
using System;

namespace Maxmin
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n, Max, Min, k;
            n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            k = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Max = Min = k;

            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                k = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                if(Max<=k)
                {
                    Max = k;
                }
                if(Min>k)
                {
                    Min = k;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Min=" + Min);
            Console.WriteLine("Max=" + Max);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А что вы вводите, какие числа? Могу предположить, что вы вводите числа с плавающей точкой или несколько чисел через пробел в одной строке.

Comment: С этим кодом всё в порядке.